# Digite Enterprise: Anybody knows about migration from Digite to MS Project Server?

Tags: migration, ms-project, ms-project-server-2010

I am looking at a possible migration from Digite Enterprise to MS Project Server. I want to migrate all data for a number of projects, including timesheets, issues, risks to EPMS.

Comment: People who vote for closing should provide reasons/justifications for it. This is a collaboration platform!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is only possible for exporting Projects using Digite MSP Integration.

In My opinion, Digite is a Great product for managing all these than MSP ;-)

Comment: Can you please share any link to "Digite MSP Integration"?

Comment: MSP integration is an out of box option in all Digite Enterprise versions. If you can let me know the version they I will be able to guide you.
Please refer our [Website](http://www.digite.com/products/swiftalm.html) for more info.